# Files not installing in the vendor sub-folder of ProgramFiles

Tags: wix

I am trying to put my files into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\VENDOR-NAME\PRODUCT-NAME" folder, but they are not getting installed. Going blind trying to see where I am going wrong. Please help. The relevant code is:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" >
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="MyProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="cmp_FinderOfFiles.exe" Guid="GUID-HERE">
      <File Id="file_FinderOfFiles.exe" 
            Name="FinderOfFiles.exe" 
            Source="$(var.FinderOfFiles.TargetDir)FinderOfFiles.exe"
            Checksum="yes"
            KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>   
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Is the latter `ComponentGroup` included into the `Product`? This can be done by referencing it from inside the `Product` element with `ComponentGroupRef` element.

Comment: In my `Product\Feature` node I added the reference `<ComponentRef Id="MyProductComponents"/>` and it fails to build with the error `Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:MyProductComponents'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Yan, for your pointer. Once I gave it some thought I realized I needed
`<ComponentGroupRef Id="MyProductComponents" />`
instead.

Comment: Indeed! Good to know you've spotted it. ;-)